# How to construct the combined transformation matrix that adjusts this rectangle.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, transformation

[image: example]

Like what is shown above, dashed line constructed rectangle is the original one, and the solid constructed rectangle is the target we want to transform.

So we can see that points of the original one are (-1,0)(1,0)(-1,5)(1,5) and the points of target are (-5,2)(-5,3)(5,2)(5,3). Construct the combined transformation matrix that adjusts this rectangle.

The idea I use is to find the changes of scalling and translating Sx Sy Tx and Ty.
And then plug these number I find into these two and multiply them together.[image: equation]

Then I find

Sx = 5

Sy = 1/5

Tx = -4

Ty = 2 Such that
[image: stepone]

When I tried (-1,0) to test it, what I want to get is (-5,2) But I got
[image: result]

What is wrong with my process? I am not sure how to translate shape if the negative quadrant occurs?

Also, I tried to translate one corner of the original one to the origin. So that 
Sx = 1

Sy = 1

Tx = 1

Ty = 0

And then I got
[image: try two]
When I test (-1,0), it works. And then I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

The scaling is with respect to the origin. You need to translate the old rectangle so that its center is the origin, re-scale it, then translate it back.

Comment: what you mean "translate it back"? Actually I tried translate one corner of the original one to the origin which just moves to right on grid and it works. After that I don't what should I do.

Comment: "Translate it back" means "translate the origin to the center". But if you want to translate the corner to the origin, do magnification, and then translate the origin to the corresponding corner of the new rectangle, that should work as well.